# How to Connect and Send Commands to Windows 7 / Server Using RDP Command Line?

Tags: windows-7, linux, windows, ssh, remote-desktop

I am trying to automate connections to a windows 7 / Server box using RDP and from there I want to be able to use putty from command line and issue some commands on the linux box.

The output should be sent back to the initial Windows box for further processing.

Bottomline, I would like to have a ssh-like connection for windows while using the RDP service - just like I would use RDP in command mode.

What would be the best approach in solving this matter.

I cannot install a 3rd party software neither on the windows or linux boxes so this must be done with the tools supplied on windows.